# How to amend the Git commit message through Python?

Tags: git, subprocess, git-commit, gitpython

I have used `subprocess.check_output` to get the result of Git command but I can't think of a way how to update the commit message that we do with the command `git commit -amend` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Python as the editor, so amending uses `GIT_EDITOR` which can be your own Python command to manipulate text, this can even be a call to Python containing a code-snippet, e.g.

```py
import os
import subprocess
# Add "Some Appended Text!" after the commit message.
subprocess.check_call(
    ("git", "commit", "--amend"),
    env={
        **os.environ,
        "GIT_EDITOR": "".join([
            """'%s' -c "import sys\n""" % sys.executable,
            """file = sys.argv[-1]\n""",
            """with open(file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as fh: data = fh.read()\n""",
            """data = '\\n'.join([l for l in data.split('\\n') if not l.startswith('#')])\n""",
            """data = data.rstrip() + '\\n\\nRef: !%d\\n'\n""" % args.pr,
            """with open(file, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as fh: fh.write(data)\n" - """,
        ]),
    }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a commit message to `git commit --amend`. For example:

```
git commit --amend -m "This is a new commit message"
```

Or you can read a new commit message from a file:

```
git commit --amend -F commitmsg
```

Or you can read it from *stdin*:

```
echo "This is a new commit message" | git commit --amend -F-
```

You could use any one of these mechanisms through Python.

Comment: What does `-F` stands for ?

Comment: That is how you read a commit message from a file...which I thought I had stated clearly in the answer, but if it was unclear I apologize.